Is every complex linear operator diagonalizable?
I'm currently reading and working through "Linear Algebra Done Wrong" by Treil. I see the following
If an operator $A : V \rightarrow V$ has exactly $n = \dim V$ distinct eigenvalues, then it is diagonalizable.
Then we have
If $A : V \rightarrow V$ is diagonalizable , then it has exactly $n = \dim V$ eigenvalues (counting multiplicities)
Do these two statements imply that any $A$ over the complex numbers is diagonalizable? Since the eigenvalues of $A$ are the solutions to polynomials, and then the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that there will be n complex solutions counting multiplicity...what am I missing something or is this true?

If the eigenvalues of $A$ are $distinct$, then it is diagonalizable.

(-1) "Do these two statements imply that any A
over the complex numbers is diagonalizable?": clearly not. In the second statement, diagonalizability is a hypothesis, not a conclusion. And in the first one, the assumption ($n$ distinct eigenvalues) discards many operators $A$. I voted to close this post for unclarity but it is moreover a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926798

You need to distinguish algebraic and geometric multiplicities here. What's true is that

$A$ is diagonalizable iff it has $n$ eigenvalues with geometric multiplicity, and
over $\mathbb{C}$, every $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues with algebraic multiplicity.

But these are not the same! Explicitly, any $n \times n$ Jordan block has a single eigenvalue $\lambda$ whose algebraic multiplicity is $n$ but whose geometric multiplicity is only $1$. So, for example, $A = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, for any value of $\lambda$, and every $2 \times 2$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ which is not diagonalizable is conjugate to a matrix of this form; this is a special case of the Jordan normal form theorem.
